# Drop down menu with defaults using dash in python

Tags: drop-down-menu, pycharm, default, dashboard, plotly-dash

I am new to pycharm/dash. I have two files:

File 1: default temperature and climate for each city:

[image]

and File 2: The options available for temperature and climate:

[image]

**Desired output:** I want to create a drop down menu for temperature and climate, city is fixed. Note:The output should have two rows for city with 4 options in the drop down for climate and 5 options in the drop down for temperature.

I tried to combine the two tables and create drop down menus for temperature and climate but it does not work. However, if I try it with temperature and climate having the same length, it works. I'm not sure if I missed out something for different length columns, and also I still have yet to figure out how to set the default...

below is my code:

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_table
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict


app = dash.Dash(__name__)


df1 =  pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\xxx\\Downloads\\test_climate.xlsx')
df2 =  pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\xxx\\Downloads\\climate_options.xlsx')
df= df1.append(df2, sort = False)



app.layout = html.Div([
    dash_table.DataTable(
        id='table-dropdown',
        data=df.to_dict('records'),
        columns=[
            {'id': 'climate', 'name': 'climate', 'presentation': 'dropdown''},
            {'id': 'temperature', 'name': 'temperature', 'presentation': 'dropdown'},
            {'id': 'city', 'name': 'city'},
        ],

        editable=True,
        dropdown={
            'climate': {
                'options': [
                    {'label': i, 'value': i}
                    for i in df['climate'].unique()
                ]
            },
            'temperature': {
                 'options': [
                    {'label': i, 'value': i}
                    for i in df['temperature'].unique()
                ]
            }
        }
    ),
    html.Div(id='table-dropdown-container')
])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Pls advise and Thanks in advance!

Regards,

Comment: Can you please expand and edit your question on what you are trying to achieve as your output. When running the code I am getting a table which just has lots of editable dropdown cells. Are you trying to have two rows for each city with dropdowns for climate and temperature?

Comment: Hi Ollie, Yes exactly, I only want two rows for city with dropdowns for climate and temperature. I will edit the question so that it is clearer, thanks for pointing it out.